# Faster way to find monthly differences from present?

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

```
Tbl <- Tbl %>%
  mutate(
    year = actyr + 1900,
    Date = as.Date(paste0(year, "-", actmo, "-30")),
    Months = round((as.integer(difftime(ymd(20171230),ymd    (Date),units="weeks"))/4),0))
```

The above code uses lubridate and dplyr. This works well for smaller data sets, and will run in a few seconds. The result being the number of months away from the date specified. However, when working with larger data sets, in the millions of rows, R crashes. Is there a more efficient way of finding the difference in months from a specified date?

Comment: Can you share your smaller data for reference?

Comment: Are you really creating dates as at the 30th day of the month (which is how I read `Date = as.Date(paste0(year, "-", actmo, "-30")`)? What about February with 28 or 29 days?

Comment: The day, in this scenario doesn't matter, as long as they are all the same. The data doesn't have days. However, to coerce it properly, I suppose a day of 20 would work better, especially for date functions. Good point.

Comment: Have you tried integer division?  Change:  `Months =  difftime(ymd(20171230),ymd    (Date),units="weeks")) %/% 4`

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your memory limit.

```
memory.limit()
```

Tells you how much you can use with R.  You can change it with `memory.size(55000)`

I did that with a tibble that had 74 mil rows and 9 columns.  Using dplyr is the best option and with the mutate.

Comment: Working on a server actually. I am not entirely sure where the server runs, but I do not believe size would be an issue. I did try and run that, but received an error that it only works on Windows.

Comment: Have you tried library(foreign) or library(ff).  Both help manage large data files.  If you cannot increase your memory.limit you can always slice your data into more manageable chunks.  This is not the most efficient way but might work